# Ubuntu 18.04 OVA default credentials

Tags: system-installation

What's the default credentials of Ubuntu 18.04 OVA (https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/release/ubuntu-18.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.ova)

Answer (score 6):

you can create a new user or change passwd in grub Recovery Mode.

1. holding `shift` key for grub menu when booting virtualbox vm
2. select Advanced -> recovery mode, then select root and press `enter`
3. `passwd` or add user:

   ```bsh
   adduser <username>
   usermod -aG sudo <username>
   ```

Comment: the is the real answer.

Answer (score 4):

The default user is `ubuntu`. Password for this user must be specified while deploying process.
For example for VMware player deployment process:
[Setting password for a default user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfMsL.png)

Comment: Tried this and does not work, did it work for you?

Comment: Sure, as I said created VM with VMWare and provide a password on VM creation step. After this login in shell with user `ubuntu` and password.

Answer (score 0):

Default password as `ubuntu` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu cloud images require cloud-init functionality to create loginable users (and whatever else needs to be done on boot).   it sounds like vmware abstracts cloud-init away, and wraps it in vmware a "set user password" gui function, for ease of end-user. i have not tried specifing cloud-init, other than ec2, but sounds like cloud-init user solution would resolve this issue, for any virtualization that supports cloud-init (vmware, openstack, etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you came here after a very long search trying to get Ubuntu cloud image working on Virt-manager, because you cant login see here. It includes how to specify the password which is generated by cloud-init: [What are the different versions available as Ubuntu cloud-images?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1375589/what-are-the-different-versions-available-as-ubuntu-cloud-images)